# Custom validation TeamCity

Tags: validation, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I use TeamCity as CI. 
And I need to make some custom validations of my project.
So, can I create some custom tool(application or something another), which will be work as runner(build step) and returns some result(i.e. valid or not valid) and if result will be not valid, Teamcity stop buid process?

Comment: With stopped build you will not see any problem (red build), so it may be better to fail build if some validation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a console app then execute it using a command line runner. If the validation you want fails, call the REST API to cancel the build:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildCanceling%2FStopping:

For example:

```
curl -v -u user:password --request POST "http://localhost:7000/app/rest/buildQueue/<buildLocator>" --data "<buildCancelRequest comment='' readdIntoQueue='true' />" --header "Content-Type: application/xml"
```